# Ways to get field dependencies programmatically

Tags: entities

Let's say I have field 'abc' which is dependent on some other field d1, d2 of same content type.

Is there any way to get all the dependencies of field 'abc' programmatically.

Comment: How do you consider a field dependency? Is there any module you have used?

Comment: I m using Conditional Fields module version 7.x-3.0-alpha1

Comment: I believe you need to dig into the conditional field module's code. You will surely find a way to get dependencies.